# Clang Analyzer in Xcode 4.4 not showing any issues

Tags: xcode, clang, static-analysis

Running Analyze on my project in Xcode 4.4 shows no issues. To test this I commented out some release statements and still clang does not show anything. It used to show a handful of issues from 3rd party libs and now, nada. What can I do to get it working again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by going into **Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations** and changing the location of derived data to **Default**. (Not sure how it became undefaulted)